# .NET GraphQL type: ABCModel cannot be coerced effectively to a GraphQL type

Tags: graphql

I am running into this error and failing to find / understand what I am seeing on Google and the Star Wars example. Here is my setup. I'm thinking you don't need to see the models.

```
public class IType : ObjectGraphType<IModel>
{
    public IType()
    {
        Field(x => x.iD);
        Field(x => x.fullName);
        Field(x => x.email);            
    }
}

public class PType : ObjectGraphType<PModel>
{
    public PType()
    {
        Field(x => x.PID);
        Field(x => x.PValue);
        Field<ListGraphType<SType>>("SKS");          
    }
}

public class SType : ObjectGraphType<SModel>
{
    public SType()
    {
        Field(x => x.SID);
        Field(x => x.Name);   
    }
}
```

Now I created a model and a type that combines all of the above into one complex object.

```
public class IPModel
{
    public string iD {get;set;}
    public string fullName{get;set;}
    public string email{get;set;}
    public PModel PWS{get;set;}
}

public class PModel
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public List<SModel> SKS{get;set;}=new List<SModel>();
}


public class IPType : ObjectGraphType<IPModel>
{
    public IPType()
    {
        Field(x => x.iD);
        Field(x => x.fullName);
        Field(x => x.email);
        Field<PModel>(x => x.PWS);   //Error occurs resolving this type
    }
}
```

My error occurs on the line with the comment above.

> Innermost exception    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : The type: PModel cannot be coerced effectively to a GraphQL type.

Now I'm sure this is not a bug but a lack of knowledge / understanding on my part. What am I doing wrong?

(Cross posted here: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/1009#issue-408196708 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Disclaimer: This works but not sure why and if it is the correct solution).

For some reason it seems that **ANY** model / type that contains a list cannot be resolved via lambda.

Field() from the .NET GraphQL Assembly has the following signature.

```
#region Assembly GraphQL, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// GraphQL.dll
#endregion

public FieldType Field(Type type, string name, string description = null, QueryArguments arguments = null, Func<ResolveFieldContext<TSourceType>, object> resolve = null, string deprecationReason = null);
```

Now these parameters are resolved from the lambda expression **EXCEPT** it seems when a `List<T>` / `ListGraphType` are involved then you have to specify the parameters explicitly.

Note: PModel is not a list but it contains a list.

So I changed it to:

```
public class IPType : ObjectGraphType<IPModel>
{
   public IPType()
   {
     Field(x => x.iD);
     Field(x => x.fullName);
     Field(x => x.email);
     Field<PModel>("PWS"); //NOTE:replaced lamda above with string value for name
   }
}
```

### Update

I had cross posted to [github graphql-dotner](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/1009) and got this solution there, which I like better (credit: bogdancice).

> Try it this way: `Field(x => x.PWS, nullable:true, type:typeof(PType));`